# MacBook lost wireless connection

Tags: network, wifi

My MacBook Pro lost wireless connection.

Everything was working fine when the connection suddenly stopped.
My mac can still connect via ethernet cable, so I know the modem and router and everything are working. Other wireless devices (phones and computers) can connect to the router, so I know the router is working. I've tried restarting my mac, and that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

I'm on OS 10.6.8

Comment: That's bizarre -- I have had exactly the same problem today. MacBookPro6,2 running 10.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (strangely, on the same day). My MacBook Pro would see and connect to the router but not be allowed past it, to the internet. Other devices had no such trouble, and resets of both the laptop and the router had no effect.

In my case, I had set a certain maximum number of DHCP clients on my router, and all the entries had been taken up. Raising this number by one allowed my MacBook to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Check your router. Is the area you live in currently offline right now? Or did you download software or software packages? Some may not work well with wireless. Also, you may want to restart the router, because it may also be having too much pressure on it and it may just look like it is ok. Also you might have accidentally connected to the wrong wifi, so check that as well. Also check the relationship between the modem and the router. If all else fails, call in a technician.